This contract is safe?

function burn() public requireInitialized() returns (bool _success) {
    // Rate will be calculated based on the nearest decimal
    uint256 _amount = SKCInterface(skcTokenContract).balanceOf(msg.sender);
    uint256 _wei = mul(_amount, weiPerNanoSKC);
    require(address(this).balance >= _wei, "Contract does not have enough funds");
    require(SKCInterface(skcTokenContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, _amount), "No SKCs or SKC account not authorized");
    address _user = msg.sender;
    (_success,) = _user.call.value(_wei)('');
    require(_success, "Transfer of Ether failed");
    emit Refund(_user, _amount, _wei);
  } 

Is this code vulnerable to reentracy?



Well, by using low level function call you are just giving your control-flow to the caller, which you shouldn't be doing.Use openzeppelin or other secured contracts.

it seems ok, considering that
require(SKCInterface(skcTokenContract).transferFrom(...), "...");
is called before
(_success,) = _user.call.value(_wei)('');
You should check require(_amount > 0) before transferFrom() but transferFrom() will fail if user's balance is too low
Please don't take this for granted because more context would be needed to be 100% sure, I suggest you to implement tests on this, or add OZ NonReentracncy modifier
Contact me if you need a proper audit.
